# Do civil servants in Greece receive 3 days of holiday for donating blood?

Tags: greece

> Greek civil servants get three days leave for donating blood.
>
> A civil servant would be allowed to donate blood twice a year. This means, he could claim an extra 6-day leave. I cannot tell, if this blood-donation benefit has been scrapped as well.

source: [keeptalkinggreece](http://www.keeptalkinggreece.com/2013/09/13/greek-civil-servants-enjoyed-extra-6-day-paid-leave-for-using-computers-at-work/), 09/2013

I was not able to verify if civil servants are still allowed to take these holidays. If they are, is there any other country in Europe with such a high reward (in terms of holidays)?

Comment: I see two different claims: 3 days of holiday for donating blood and 6 days of holiday for using a computer

Comment: @gerrit computer leave is a different matter, AFAIK it was scrapped. "6-day leave" in the quote above means 2x3-day leave from donating blood.

Comment: "Computer leave" was scrapped. It was a relic from CRT days anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The blood donation leave is 2 days, including the day you donate. You cannot transfer it (although it may have happened). This is a motivation for blood donation because Greece imports blood supplies and the public sector has the largest workforce and is the one who pays for importing blood anyway.

For those who can read Greek the law is [here](http://www.ydmed.gov.gr/wp-content/uploads/20140616_kwdikas_ypalilwn_dimosion_kai_npdd.pdf). Chapter 6, article 50, paragraph 5.

> Employees (singular in the original) who respond to an invitation for emergency donation coverage, as well as employees who participate in organised blood donation are entitled to 2 days of leave of absence, fully paid.

Answer (score 5):

The article [BLOOD DONOR BEHAVIOUR IN GREECE: IMPLICATIONS FOR HEALTH POLICY](http://cyrus.tcdn.teicrete.gr/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=2MLUpf5j-dQ%3D&tabid=1089) Soc. Sci. Med. Vol. 38, No. 10, pp. 1461-1467, discusses:

> the right for a 2-day leave from work

also phrased as

> Two-day leave of absence from work during blood donation

and

> Six-day military leave

See also [Factors that motivate and hinder blood donation in Greece](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2440532/) Transfus Med. 2007 Dec; 17(6): 443–450 :

> a large number of volunteers report having hidden the truth in the screening questionnaire so that they are allowed to donate blood in order to be granted leave from work

and

> donors belonged to the armed forces. This last group is highly motivated to donate voluntarily as they are compensated with days off from duty

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but these papers are 21 and 8 years old, respectively. I believe that many of the bonuses and privileges in the Greek public sector had to be scrapped after 2010 in order to satisfy the creditors, so this information might be outdated.

Comment: @alkamid adamo seems to have a current answer